# .find works for me in one procedure but not another

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have the code below. Essentially, it grabs unique values of a certain range in each worksheet and adds it to a range on the side of the same worksheet.

The .find method is not working for me like it does in another procedure and I would like an explanation why or what I am doing wrong or the difference between the behavior of the code when written differently. make sense?

```
    sub methodtwo()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strDATE As String
    Dim datehr As Range


    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 4
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Set datehr = Sheets(i).Range("H2", Sheets(i).Range("H2").End(xlDown))
                For Each cell In datehr
                        strDATE = cell.Value
                        Set cell = Sheets(i).Range("L1:L400").Find(What:=strName)

                            If cell Is Nothing Then
                                Sheets(i).Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = cell

                            End If

                Next cell
        Next i

    End Sub
```

below is the code I have written before and a reference for writing the code above. In the code below, the find method works perfectly and adds unique values to the designated range...the code above does not.

```
Sub methodone()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim a As Range
Dim al As Range
Dim strName As String

For Each sh In Worksheets
    sh.Activate
    sh.Range("K1").Activate
    Set al = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A13000")

        For Each a In al
                strName = a.Value
                Set Cell = ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K400").Find(What:=strName)

                    If Cell Is Nothing Then
                        ActiveSheet.Range("K1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = a

                    End If

        Next a

Next sh


End Sub
```

I wanted the methodtwo() to do the exact same thing as methodone() except on the last 4 sheets.

Is the problem obvious? I'm working on my attention to detail..especially when using a previously written code for reference.

Comment: methodtwo seems to be looking for `strName` - which isn't declared

Comment: ahh oh dear...I didn't change it to strDATE. Thanks so much. I really should be more careful. Now there is another problem. the following line in the IF statement returns error 1004 application defined or object defined error `sheets(I).range("L1").end(xldown).offset(1,0).value = cell` which was fixed by replacing `cell` with `strDATE`

Comment: @BezukhovPierre Edit your post with the new issue and clarify your question.  You shouldn't be asking new questions in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

for methodone() I just had to change strNAME to strDATE which is a detail error when converting one procedure to the other. I also changed the "cell" after the IF statement to "strDATE"

```
    sub methodtwo()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strDATE As String
    Dim datehr As Range


    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 4
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Set datehr = Sheets(i).Range("H2", Sheets(i).Range("H2").End(xlDown))
                For Each cell In datehr
                        strDATE = cell.Value
                        Set cell = Sheets(i).Range("L1:L400").Find(What:=strDATE)

                            If cell Is Nothing Then
                                Sheets(i).Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = strDATE

                            End If

                Next cell
        Next i
     end sub
```

Comment: Adding `Option Explicit` to your modules can help catch those sneaky variables.